# Strange paths in Task Manager: "\??\C:\Windows\etc.."

Tags: path, task-manager

When looking a the list of processes for a different reason, I noticed something odd:
[image: TaskManager]
There's four instances of conhost, but I haven't seen paths like those before.. Can anyone tell me what the purpose is of placing the "\??\" in front of the path?

Any other remarks or thoughts about what you see in the list are also welcome!

*This question was partly asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/701989/windows-xp-pro-sp3-stop-changes-to-security-software-registry-keys-set-by-unk/702739) already, but the "\??\" part wasn't answered.*

Comment: WinAPI related. Used to get around MAX_PATH (260 character) limitation. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows for more information.

Comment: I'm inclined to believe you, but both the question and the msdn article talk about `\\?\` and not `\??\`. Could you elaborate on this?